# Alternative to ASP.NET LoginStatus Control in C#

Tags: asp.net, loginstatus

I wish to come up with an alternative to using the ASP.NET LoginStatus control.

At the moment, on my master page I have a link to a Login page which then allows users to sign in using a 'Login' control. When the user is logged in I wish the Login link to change to Logout and when the Logout link is pressed for it to log the user out and return to the homepage.

Thank you.

Comment: This is exactly what Login control does: `Detects the user's authentication state and toggles the state of a link to log in to or log out of a Web site.` What do you want to change in this behavior?

Comment: It's for an assignment and we get more marks for making our site as accessible as possible. The LoginStatus control using javascript which I why I need an alternative.

Comment: @markthornton90 **LoginStatus** Server Control doesn't use Javascript. If you want to reinvent wheel, you can make your own **UserControl** or **ServerControl**.

Comment: @Win it definitely does. Disable javascript in your browser and try hitting 'login' - nothing happens.

Comment: **__doPostBack** is a bare minimum JavaScript. Without using any JavaScript, a lot of ASP.Net controls will break such LinkButton. Are you saying that you are going to make your own Server Controls like GridView without JavaScript? Help yourself!

Comment: @Win No..i'm saying that our lecturer has told us to avoid Javascript where possible and that by replacing LoginStatus with our own will result in a higher mark